# Unable to iterate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have got issue when I work out on the ng-repeat directive, since I am a beginner , unable to resolve it on my own.

```js
var myModule = angular.module("myFirst",[]);

myModule.controller("cont", function($scope){
var employees = [
{name: "Manju", age :"23", rank:"2"},
{name: "SivaSankari", age :"23", rank:"1"},
{name: "Gayathri", age :"23", rank:"1"},
];
$scope.employees = employees;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html  ng-app="myFirst">
  <head>
    <title> My workout|ngRepeat
    </head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="cont">
<table>
<thead>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Postions</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="x in employees">
<td>{{employees.name}}</td>
<td>{{employees.age}}</td>
<td>{{employees.position}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>

</body>
  <html>
```

Also I have doubt on key that is x. Is ok to give any key value ?
Can any one please help me to resolve and understand ?
Thanks.

Comment: you should write as `<td>{{x.name}}</td>` not `employees.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

You have to use `x` instead of `employees` because `employees` is your array and `x` the current item

**Second**

You were trying to access the property `position` that is not existing inside your object. You should call `rank`

```js
var myModule = angular.module("myFirst", []);

myModule.controller("cont", function($scope) {
  var employees = [{
    name: "Manju",
    age: "23",
    rank: "2"
  }, {
    name: "SivaSankari",
    age: "23",
    rank: "1"
  }, {
    name: "Gayathri",
    age: "23",
    rank: "1"
  }, ];
  $scope.employees = employees;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myFirst">

<body>
  <div ng-controller="cont">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Postions</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in employees">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.age}}</td>
          <td>{{x.rank}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Hi, yup I changed the code , wrongly pasted here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.age}}</td>
<td>{{x.position}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access the properties of **`x`** not the **`employee`** array

```
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.age}}</td>
<td>{{x.position}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining x as the employee you're iterating over. So the repeat part should be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in employees">
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.age}}</td>
<td>{{x.position}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you used `ng-repeat="x in employees"` it means you're saying on each iterate assign the item to `x`, that's why you can't use any other variable other than `x`.

```
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.age}}</td>
<td>{{x.position}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your `ngRepeat` in the title tag, but your table declaration makes little sense.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in employees">
```

means that for every element (henceforth to be referred to as `x`) in the array `employees`, repeat this element viz. table row. (Make sure that's what you really want to do)

Therefore, inside your `td`, you gotta write -

```
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
```

> Also I have doubt on key that is x. Is ok to give any key value ?

If you mean to say whether you can call `x` anything else then yes, you can.
E.g.

```
<tr ng-repeat="singleEmployee in employees">
<td>{{singleEmployee.name}}</td>
```

Comment: Hi,  you said the title tag , you did not understand, sorry I thought I am getting an issue in a simple work out on ng repeat , so thought, it would be ok keep title like that. I have checked the other questions also then only kept. Thanks for the answer..

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in ng-repeat, it should be x.name not employess.name

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in employees">
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.age}}</td>
    <td>{{x.position}}</td>
    </tr>
```